# Is it possible to search for a specific HTML tag within a site using a search engine?

Tags: google-search

I want to search a single website for pages that do or do not have a canonical URL specified (`<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.site.com/pageCannonicalUrl.htm' />`). Is it possible to do this using Google?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to search the HTML source of any website using Google.

Comment: It doesn't have to be google, I'd settle for some other site or search engine with that ability...I suppose there might be some library that would be able to spider a site for specific meta tags...